# Block a button on my side bar until the user is logged in?

Tags: python, html, django

Using Django and HTML, how can I block a button on my tab bar until someone is logged in?

My sidebar:

```
<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
  <a href="/">Home</a>
  <a href="/accounts/login">Login</a>
  <a href="#">Profile</a>
  <a href="/upload">Upload</a>
  <a href="/top_photos">Top Photos</a>
  <a href="/aboutus">About Us</a>
  <a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```

Block statement:

```
{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <h1 style="text-align:right">Welcome {{ user.username }}!</h1>

{% else %}
  <div class="c">
  <p>You are not logged in, log in to recolor a photo</p>
  <a href="/upload">
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Where is button in your html code? You have used `<a>` tag everywhere not `<button>`. To disable a button you can do `<button disabled>Click Here</button>`. Using `disabled` attribute makes the button inactive functionality wise and greys out the button if speaking about visual changes. In case of `<a>` you need to completely remove href attribute if user is not logged in. But note that this is not a good choice user experience wise as this might give an impression of link not working instead of link disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `request.user.is_authenticated` instead of `user.is_authenticated`. My guess is that you aren't passing a `User` object to your template in `views.py`, but you are almost certainly passing `request`, which will contain user information if you're using Django's login system.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{% block content %}
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
  <h1 style="text-align:right">Welcome {{ user.username }}!</h1>

{% else %}
  <div class="c">
  <p>You are not logged in, log in to recolor a photo</p>
  <a href="/upload">
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```